# Send long arabic parameters in <a> tag to jsp

Tags: html, jsp, arabic

In an HTML page, I have  tags that look something like:

```
<a href="similarReferences.jsp">LONG_ARABIC_CONTENT_HERE</a>
```

The long arabic content is composed of verses of the Holy Quran. And what I would like to do, is, by clicking on that link, run a function that I have in a jsp file, that would display similar verses.

The problem I have is how to send that verse itself to the jsp file. I cannot send it via normal parameters like:

```
<a href="similarReferences.jsp?verse=LONG_ARABIC_CONTENT_HERE">LONG_ARABIC_CONTENT_HERE</a>
```

because:

- The verse can be very long (longer than the allowed length)
- It is in Arabic
- It may contain some characters that are not allowed in parameter content, like "?".

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Just send the surah+verse number for reference. Like similarReferences.jsp?surah=1&verse=1 This would be way easier to handle and run querys against anyway.

Comment: The thing is that I don't know the surah and verse IDs beforehand. I only have the textual content for now. I'll have to send it anyways to find out the IDs.